# InternetExplorerDriver configuración

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Estoy trabajando en la automatización de una página web que corre en el navegador Internet Explorer, pero al ejecutar el driver, se levanta la sesión del IE pero al rato deja de funcionar, impidiendo la captura de los elementos del DOM, alguien sabe si toca hacer alguna configuración adicional, o con que versión del IE trabaja el driver.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir mas detalles sobre las versiones? IE instalado, version de selenium, version de IE driver y version de windows. Todo esto debe estar alineado para funcionar. Por lo que cuentas alguna de ellas no es la correcta

Comment: Hola @j.barrio las versiones son las siguientes:InternetExplorer 11.309.16299.0 , selenium : 3.12, IE Driver 3.11.1 Windows 64

Comment: Yo me descargaria la última versión del driver de ie y si no arranca ve descargando la anterior y así sucesivamente. En teoría con esa versión de selenium la última sería la correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Podes probar con esta configuración creando una nueva clase "controller".

public class Controller {
static WiniumDriver driver= null;
static WiniumDriverService service= null;
static DesktopOptions options= null;
protected WebDriverWait driverWait= null;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws IOException{
options = new DesktopOptions();
options.setApplicationPath("C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
File driverPath = new File("C:Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
service= new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(driverPath).usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true).withSilent(false).buildDesktopService();
service.start();
}

fíjate bien la opción de inspección de elementos y fijate los ID o Name. También  la opción de buscar los elementos desde otro navegador. Mientras que no sea una aplicación homologada donde te permita solo correrla desde Internet Explorer.
Pasanos mas info de tu problema y te ayudo.